# Printing an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am learning Java by tutorial on YouTube. I changed code a little and the result was weird. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class array {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int  bucky[]={1,2,3,4,5};
        change(bucky);

        System.out.println(bucky);
    }

    public static void change(int x[]){
        // change the array
        for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++)
             x[counter]+=5;
    }
}
```

But the result was `[I@2a139a55`

The code on the tutorial is:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class array {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int  bucky[]={1,2,3,4,5};
        change(bucky);
      for(int y:bucky)
        System.out.println(y);// here!
    }

    // change the array
    public static void change(int x[]){
        for(int counter=0;counter<x.length;counter++)
            x[counter]+=5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that **bucky** is and object, even if it is an array of primitives ints, so you need to use the correct way to print that object...
in your case the right way to print an array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bucky));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(bucky);
```

because `System.out.println(bucky);` is invoking the `toString()` method of the super class `Object` which just returns the class name and the `hashCode()`in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

To print an array, use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

So in your case, `array` would be replaced by `bucky`.